# php class for mysqli, to make sure mysqli is never left open after usage?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

class connection
{
    public $host, $username, $password, $database;

    function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database)
    {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    function MySQLi()
    {
        return new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->MySQLi());
    }
}

?>
```

Is destructing mysqli connections inside of a class a bad idea? Or should one stick to standard mysqli objects and just close connections like this?

```
$bedtime = new mysqli(....);
$bedtime->query("INSERT..");
$bedtime->close();
```

Comment: You're assuming that the destruction of objects (and the invocation of the destructor) is more reliable than the automagical freeing of a resource and its related clean-up mechanism (otherwise the title and the question would make no sense). Are you sure of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deconstruction won't work, because if you do something like

```
$conn = $connection->MySQLi(.......);
```

even if you `unset($connection)`, `$conn` will remain active.

Stick with normal objects if that's your target.